# Deploy Google Cloud Bigtable with deployment manager

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable, google-deployment-manager

I am trying to deploy a Bigtable instance with the following YAML config file:

```
resources:
- name: foo-bigtable-instance
  type: bigtableadmin.v2.instance
  properties:
     name: foo
     displayName: Foo Bigtable Instance
     type: Development
```

When I invoke *gcloud deployment-manager deployments create* I get the following error...

```
ERROR: (gcloud.deployment-manager.deployments.create) Error in Operation [operation-1545154324304-57d4f469f9081-51e37137-270e5638]: errors:
- code: MISSING_REQUIRED_FIELD
  location: /deployments/sam-poc-deployment/resources/foo-bigtable-instance->$.properties->$.parent
  message: |-
    Missing required field 'parent' with schema:
    {
      "type" : "string"
    }
```

What is the required 'parent' property?  The error suggests it is an object with a single field named "type".

But what does the 'parent' represent?  And what are the allowed values for the 'type'?  The 'parent' property is not mentioned in the [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/reference/admin/rest/v2/projects.instances).

Answer (score 3):

There are some errors in your **yaml file**. I believe that this modifications can solve your issue:

```
resources:
- type: bigtableadmin.v2.instance
  name: foo-bigtable-instance
  properties:
    instanceId: [AN_INSTANCE_ID]
    parent: projects/[YOUR_PROJECT]
    instance:
      displayName: Foo Bigtable Instance
      type: DEVELOPMENT
    clusters:
      initial:
        defaultStorageType: HDD
        location: projects/[YOUR_PROJECT]/locations/[PREFERRED_LOCATION ]
```

Also, I noticed that you are using the documentation of [`projects.instances`](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/reference/admin/rest/v2/projects.instances) but, in this case, is better to use the one for [`projects.instances.create`](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/reference/admin/rest/v2/projects.instances/create). It has more information about the instance creation and the needed fields. You can also refer to the [various examples](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/deploymentmanager-samples/tree/master/examples/v2/bigtable/python) provided by GCP about this kind of operations.

Comment: This was really helpful, but I found that I had to change the resource type to "gcp-types/pubsub-v1:projects.topics"

Answer (score 2):

It's somewhat confusing as the `parent` is actually defined in the path of the [create operation](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/reference/admin/rest/v2/projects.instances/create#path-parameters) for that resource. It represents the project owning the Bigtable instance. See the [Bigtable snippet](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/deploymentmanager-samples/blob/master/google/resource-snippets/bigtableadmin-v2/bigtable.jinja) for a better idea of usage.